# Place ImageView on another image in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, nslayoutconstraint

I have an Image View 'V' and an image 'I'. My task is to place 'V' on the top right corner of 'I'. As like below the 'semi stitched' image is an image need to place on main image.

[image]

I have a class 'ProductDetail' which implements 'UIPageViewController' for showing sliding images. In 'UIPageViewController' class the view for main image is 'contentImageView' and in ViewDidLoad() I have set the image for contentImageView as,

```
contentImageView!.hnk_setImageFromURL( imageURL)
```

I tried with, `NSLayoutConstraint(item: 'V', attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: 'I', attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)`

But it doesnt worked for me. What is the correct way to give constraints to my 'V' imageView (small image) to be on right top corner of 'I' bigger image.

Currently I can set the 'V' (small image) on top-right corner of bigger imageView but I want it on bigger image not on bigger image View.

Comment: That is the proper way, except you need both .trailing and .top; also don't forget to also add width/height either with direct values or proportional values otherwise UIKit will likely complain.

Comment: It looks perfect, what is your expectation?

Comment: Xcode says , terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException. Constraint items must each be an instance of UIView, or UILayoutGuide.'

Comment: Bcz item is must be anyobject not a string. How you can give constraints w.r.t string, it must be any UI component with whom you refer.

Comment: So how should I refer image of 'contentImageView' (UIImageView)

Comment: Take reference from [here](http://www.knowstack.com/swift-nslayoutconstraint-programatically-sample-code/). Still something unclear then let me nkwo.

Comment: The above reference's examples all deal with View's but as I mentioned that I can make constraints with imageView but not with the image itself. And also 'image' above is not a string it's an UIImage object As I fetched it from contentImageView.image

Comment: Do you want to *merge* the two images? Or do you just want to display the red image in the correct location?

Comment: second choice, Just want to display the red image on the top-right corner of the big image.

Answer (score 0):

Couple ways to do this --- here is one method...

**Edit:** Slightly edited original code. This uses a `UIImageView` extension which returns the actual frame of the image when the image view is set to `Aspect-Fit`

Assuming you have an image view to hold the "item" image, I'm calling it `combinedImageView`, and it is square (ratio `1:1`).

You may want to play with the percentage / size of the "overlay" to get the size you want.

Note: you can click on the below images to see them actual-size.

```
extension UIImageView {
    var contentClippingRect: CGRect {
        guard let image = image else { return bounds }
        guard contentMode == .scaleAspectFit else { return bounds }
        guard image.size.width > 0 && image.size.height > 0 else { return bounds }

        let scale: CGFloat
        if image.size.width > image.size.height {
            scale = bounds.width / image.size.width
        } else {
            scale = bounds.height / image.size.height
        }

        let size = CGSize(width: image.size.width * scale, height: image.size.height * scale)
        let x = (bounds.width - size.width) / 2.0
        let y = (bounds.height - size.height) / 2.0

        return CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: size.width, height: size.height)
    }
}

class RedBandViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var combinedImageView: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // make sure imageView is set to Aspect-Fit
        combinedImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

        // make sure images are valid
        if let mainImage = UIImage(named: "ItemA"),
            let overlayImage = UIImage(named: "SemiStitched") {

            // set the "main" image
            combinedImageView.image = mainImage

            // instantiate new imageView
            let overlayImageView = UIImageView(image: overlayImage)

            // we'll use auto-layout
            overlayImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

            // add the overlay imageView to the "combined" imageView
            combinedImageView.addSubview(overlayImageView)

            // get the frame of the aspect-fit image content
            let fitRect = combinedImageView.contentClippingRect

            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

                // anchor overlayImageView to top / trailing
                overlayImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: combinedImageView.topAnchor, constant: fitRect.origin.y),
                overlayImageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: combinedImageView.trailingAnchor, constant: (fitRect.origin.x + fitRect.size.width) - combinedImageView.frame.width),

                // constrain overlayImageView to 1/4 (25%) of the combinedImageView width
                // this will keep the "red banner" at a consistent size, regardless of image
                overlayImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: combinedImageView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.25),

                // or, constrain overlayImageView to 1/4 (25%) of the width of the Apect-Fit image,
                // this will keep the "red banner" at a consistent *percentage* width of the scaled image 
                //overlayImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: fitRect.size.width * 0.25),

                // and equal height to its own width
                overlayImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: overlayImageView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1.0),

                ])

        }
    }
}
```

SemiStitched.png (white area is alpha):

[image]

ItemA.png - square image at `400 x 400`:

[image]

ItemB.png - taller than width at `229 x 345`:

[image]

ItemC.png - wider than height at `600 x 462`:

[image]

Results:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Nice one but still the problem persists since previously I also tried with combinedImageView but not with combinedImage. The issues is as [Click here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-TFhH_ILJUlzAEztHWLLV7Te9G6phAeL/view?usp=sharing) : At development site we are using [This](https://github.com/Haneke/HanekeSwift) as to cache combinedImage and assign it to the combinedImageView. I think we could do somthing with image size!

Comment: Mot sure what you mean... Is the problem that the "product" image does not fill the view? Or, you *want* the image aspect-fit, so it's centered if it's not the exact size of the view, but you are trying to get the red bar aligned with the corner of the actual image, instead of the corner of the imageView?

Comment: The main view's content mode is set to 'Aspect-fit', and the main image is also centered align, hence it is tough for me to place red label on main image.